# Convergence of a complex power series

Tags: power-series

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb C$ with $c \in \mathbb N$. Then I have to calculate the radius of convergence of the following power series:
$$
1+ \frac{ab}{c \cdot 1!} z + \frac{a (a+1)b(b+1)}{c(c+1)2!} z^2+ \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)b(b+1)(b+2)}{c(c+1)(c+2)3!}z^3 + \cdots
$$

Using the ratio-test I get that
$$
\left | \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right | = \left | \frac{(a+n)(b+n)}{(c+n)(n+1)}z \right |
$$

How can I proceed ? This is an exam-question and a given hint says to consider whether $a$ or $b$ are in $\mathbb N$ or not. I have no idea how to use the hint.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{(a+b)(b+n)}{(c+n)(n+1)}z \right| = 0
$$
Regardless of $z$ because you're dividing a polynomial of degree $1$ by a polynomial of degree $2$. So, if you went through the ratio test correctly, the radius of convergence should just be $\infty$.

---

EDIT:
As per your comment, we now have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{(a+n)(b+n)}{(c+n)(n+1)}z \right| = 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left| \frac{n^2+O(n)}{n^2+O(n)}\right| \cdot\left|z\right|=\left|z\right|
$$
Which means that although the ratio test fails when $\left|z\right|=1$, our radius of convergence is just $1$ (since the series converges for $|z|<1$).

I have no idea how to use the hint either; it seems you may have outsmarted the exam.

---

SECOND EDIT: I now understand the exam hint!  The ratio test assumes $(a+n)$ and $(b+n)$ are always non-zero.  In the event that $a$ or $b$ is a negative integer, the radius of convergence changes to $\infty$ since we will always have finitely many non-zero terms.

Comment: Oh typo. It must be $(a+n)(b+n)$ over $(c+n)(n+1)$

Comment: Unless $a$ or $b$ is zero or a negative integer. In that case the power series has only finitely many non-zero terms and the radius of convergence is infinite. - And btw., this is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function.

Comment: Ok Martin. I got it :) And otherwise if $|z| < 1$. Thank you, guys.

Comment: I accept this as answer, even though Martin made the core of the question clear to me.

Comment: Ah I guess Martin beat me to the punch there.